# ruby metaprogramming super class not inheriting

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

When I create an anonymous class with Array as the super class, the Array methods << and []= are not getting inherited.  My code below

```
class SubArray < Array
end

sa = SubArray.new
sa << "foo"
puts sa.inspect

sa_meta = Class.new(Array)
sa_meta << "foo"
puts sa_meta.inspect
```

gives the results:

```
["foo"]
lib/so_example1.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `<<' for #<Class:0x6b10b8e4> (NoMethodError)
```

My ruby version is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i386-darwin11.4.2]
```

How can I dynamically create a class, with a super-class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the Array methods << and []= are not getting inherited

Sure they are! Just don't forget to create an *instance* of the class.

```
sa_meta_klass = Class.new(Array)
sa_meta = sa_meta_klass.new
sa_meta << "foo"
puts sa_meta.inspect
# >> ["foo"]
```

Comment: Oddly, in my code that uses the class, I implemented a work around of returning the class.  *that* code instantiated an object, and reverting it to the dynamic version works!  D'oh.